# Identify the Missing Name Prefixe’s Of Gender And Audit the Issue with Expected Suggestion by Using the Gender And Marital Status Columns

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica-powercenter

i want to replace null value if gender=f and marital status=m then mrs,gender=f and marital status=s then miss, gender=m and marital status=m then mr, gender=m and marital status=s then mr please help to find out

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Of course, many people here could just give you a working query, but what will you learn then? Did you have a look on case when syntax?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to use `CASE` expression. Here's a hint, complete it yourself.

```
select ...,
  case when gender = 'F' and marital_status = 'M' then 'Mrs'
       when gender = 'F' ...
       when gender = 'M' ...
       ...
  end as gender_prefix
from ...
```